# How can I prevent my HTML elements from shifting when I make nearby elements visible with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following:

```css
 html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    input,
    select,
    button {
      width: 5em;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      padding: 0.5em;
      font-size: 1.25em;
      border-radius: 0.25em;
    }
    
    button {
      color: #131313;
      background-color: #EFEFEF;
    }
    
    form {
      width: fit-content;
    
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }
    
    form>div {
      margin-top: 1em;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    option {
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: monospace;
      color: #131313;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    
    
    #content {
      margin: 1em 2em;
    }
    
    .spinner {
      margin-left: 1em;
      border: 0.5em solid rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.15);
      border-top: 0.5em solid rgba(255, 0, 0);
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 1.75em;
      height: 1.75em;
      animation: spinme 2s linear infinite;
      z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .hidden_element {
      display: none;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .visible_element {
      display: block;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    
    @keyframes spinme {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
    
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div id="content">
      <div> Select Date: </div>
      <form>
        <div>
          <label for="year_select">
            Year:
            <select id="year_select" name="year_select">
                <option>year</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="month_select">
            Month:
            <select id="month_select" name="month_select">
              <option>month</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="day_select">
            Day:
            <select id="day_select" name="day_select">
              <option>day</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          <div class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div id="datatable_container" class="hidden_element">
        <table>
          <!-- stuff here -->
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When the page loads, the `month` and `day` selects are hidden. When a user chooses a `year`, the `month` becomes visible. When a user chooses a `month`, the `day` becomes visible. When a user chooses a `day`, an `XMLHTTPREQUEST` is sent.

When the `XMLHTTPREQUEST` is sent, I show the wait spinner. When I get the data, I hide the spinner.

Initially, when the `year`, `month`, and `day` are visible, they all align properly.

My problem is that when I make the spinner visible, it takes up new space and the `year`/`month` and `day` are shifted apart from each other.

When I make the spinner invisible again, the select all align up again.

How can I set up my `HTML` and `CSS` so that the shifting does not happen?

Comment: Don't use `display:none` in your CSS. Just use `visibililty:hidden` which will preserve the space that the element uses, but just not show it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It doesn't work, the `year`/`month` are still out of alignment with the `day`. Also, it creates this large blank space below the `year` where the future selects will be; I would prefer everything shift down, just not left-right.

Comment: So what do you want to happen? Either there has to be space for the spinner even when it's not showing, or it parts the other elements when its shows or show it in a layer above the other elements.

Comment: @AHaworth I would like (1) for all select elements to align on the right-side, even when the spinner is present, and (2) for there not to be space below `year` when `month` and `day` are not there, and no space below `month` when `day` is not there. I was hoping ther ewould be some kind of "overflow" property in `flex` to help with this.